# Cannot mount previously mountable disk

Tags: hard-drive, mount

I have a 2-TB SeaGate external drive in exFat format (I think). Yesterday I was able to mount it without a problem and, in fact, copied a bunch of important data to it. Today, it refuses to mount. I can see it in Disk Utility and on my Windows partition (Boot Camp), but not in the Finder, and I can’t mount it via Disk Utility or via the Terminal (tried `mount dev/disk2` and `mount force dev/disk2`).

The disk is not damaged. I’ve tried using my computer’s other USB port and another cable, but nothing works. I’ve used both ports with both cables to mount a different 2-TB SeaGate drive (in macOS Extended Journalled format) and other external drives, and those mount perfectly.

Running macOS Catalina (whatever number the latest update to that was). My computer is a mid-2014 15-inch MacBook Pro with Retina display.

Comment: Some drives fail between one use and the next.

Comment: How do you *know* the disk is not damaged? Also like @Solar Mike said maybe it just failed. Could be the drive itself, or the circuitry in the external enclosure, but it just *sounds* like it just failed. Drives do that, hence the need for backups. And as backups are done to drives, perhaps backup to two different drives/locations?

Comment: I know they sometimes fail. However, it wouldn’t make any sense for it to fail suddenly while sitting on a desk without being moved or touched. I understand this could be a possibility if I had moved the drive, disconnected it without ejecting it, physically damaged it or spilt something on it, but none of this happened. Furthermore, it still works perfectly on Windows.